# How to fetch a string value from server and split each characters and insert into a input text box in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: Input fiald design in html]

I have a html form to design in similar pattern as above where the value has to come from server and sit inside the blocks. My idea was to create separate input fields inside the blocks and fetch the value from the server and split each characters insert into the fields separately. So what should I do to achieve it?

Comment: i will recommended you to do all your logical thing in server side and get a list of values here in html side, After that you can put a single input box into the loop and easily fill up those data to input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete sample:

```js
function loaded() {

  var 
    elementsStr = '<b>UMRN </b>',
    i;
  
  for (i=1; i <= 21; i++) {
    
    elementsStr += '<input maxlength="1" type="text" id="text_' + i + '" class="txt">';
  }
  
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = elementsStr;
}

function run() {
  
  var 
    valueFromServer = 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKL34234234ZXCVBNM',
    i,
    letter,
    today = new Date();
    dd = ('0' + today.getDate()).slice(-2),
    mm = ('0' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2), // January starts from 0
    yyyy = '' + today.getFullYear();

  for (i=1; i <= 21; i++) {
    
    letter = valueFromServer[i-1];
    
    if (!letter) {
      
      break;
    }
    
    document.getElementById('text_' + i).value = valueFromServer[i-1];
  }
  
  document.getElementById('date_d1').value = dd[0];
  document.getElementById('date_d2').value = dd[1];
  
  document.getElementById('date_m1').value = mm[0];
  document.getElementById('date_m2').value = mm[1];
  
  document.getElementById('date_y1').value = yyyy[0];
  document.getElementById('date_y2').value = yyyy[1];
  document.getElementById('date_y3').value = yyyy[2];
  document.getElementById('date_y4').value = yyyy[3];
}
```

```css
.txt {
  
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body onload='loaded()'>
  <p id="content">
    
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p id="contentForDate">
    
    <b>DATE </b>
    <input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_d1" class="txt"><input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_d2" class="txt">
    
    <input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_m1" class="txt"><input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_m2" class="txt">
    
    <input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_y1" class="txt"><input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_y2" class="txt">
    <input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_y3" class="txt"><input maxlength="1" type="text" id="date_y4" class="txt">
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <input type="button" value="Run!" onclick="run()">
</body>
```

Comment: THanks a lot for the help!! ;)